# why do i get titles of OO document in Gibberish

Tags: openoffice.org, locale, document-management

opening an OpenOffice file with Hebrew name, the file name appears as gibberish. in the folder it is read fine, but when i open the file, on the top bar of the document window and in the bottom of the screen it appears as gibberish.

It probably related to l18n l10n, but i don't know were to start troubleshooting this.

i use Ubuntu 10.10 with OpenOffice 3.2
[image: Here is the screenshot]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot to illustrate this?  (Maybe also one that shows the correct display.)

Comment: Did the file come from another operating system? Everything in Ubuntu is in UTF-8 by default, but not all non-Ubuntu systems use UTF-8.

Comment: @mssever, the files came from a former installation of ubuntu (i think it was 9.04) on the same machine.

Comment: This is a [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) problem, can you check the document settings and OO prefs and make sure they are set to the correct UTF-? setting for your language? Try comparing with a known good document.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) problem, can you check the document settings and OO prefs and make sure they are set to the correct UTF-? setting for your language? Try comparing with a known good document.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue before a few years back. My work around was to reload the window manager using the Compiz Fusion Icon, available in Software Center. As to why this happens and if there is a permanent fix I do not know. Best of luck!